# html in a javascript variable gives null error

Tags: javascript, html

This is my error:

> Client-side javascript error for user ATSC (127.0.0.1)
>   Details:   TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

I'm getting this error on the following code:

```
var htmlmessage =    
    <p><strong>Vul de volgende gegevens in om het inplannen af te ronden:</strong></p>
    <p>
     <form>
      <strong>Aantal in te plannen medewerkers: </strong><br>
        <input type='number' name='medewerkers' id='aantmdw' value='1'></input>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Aantal in te plannen machines: </strong><br>
        <input type='number' name='machines' id='aantmch' value='1'></input>
     </form>
    </p>;

var mdwCount = document.getElementById("aantmdw").value;
var mchCount = document.getElementById("aantmch").value;
```

It's saved into a JavaScript variable as you can see. How can I get the values out of the form to use it, instead of null?

Comment: Please update your snippet with the JS that gives you error - if the htmlmessage contains actual newlines, that is your issue. You cannot have new lines in JS

Comment: are you using angular.js ?

Comment: where's your javascript?

Comment: I don't think you can just give a javascript variable html, it'd have to be a string. I.e. wrap the html in either " or '

Comment: please provide some javascript

Comment: It is a string. I've put this html code into the html of a modal dialog. But i try to get a value after i submit the modal dialog.

Comment: Your code is literally `var htmlmessage = <p>...`? Well, yes, that's not valid Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have newlines in JavaScript string literals

If your code is actually

```
var htmlmessage = <p><strong>Vul de volgende gegevens in om het inplannen af te ronden:</strong></p>
<p>
 <form>
  <strong>Aantal in te plannen medewerkers: </strong><br>
    <input type='number' name='medewerkers' id='aantmdw' value='1'></input>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Aantal in te plannen machines: </strong><br>
    <input type='number' name='machines' id='aantmch' value='1'></input>
 </form>
</p>
```

then you need to change it to

```
var htmlmessage = '<p><strong>Vul de volgende gegevens in om het inplannen af te ronden:</strong></p>'+
'<p>'+
' <form>'+
'  <strong>Aantal in te plannen medewerkers: </strong><br>'+
'    <input type="number" name="medewerkers" id="aantmdw" value="1"></input>'+
'</p>'+
'<p>'+
'  <strong>Aantal in te plannen machines: </strong><br>'+
'    <input type="number" name="machines" id="aantmch" value="1"></input>'+
' </form>'+
'</p>';
```

Watch the quotes

OR you can use [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
var htmlmessage = `<p><strong>Vul de volgende gegevens in om het inplannen af te ronden:</strong></p>
<p>
 <form>
  <strong>Aantal in te plannen medewerkers: </strong><br>
    <input type='number' name='medewerkers' id='aantmdw' value='1'></input>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Aantal in te plannen machines: </strong><br>
    <input type='number' name='machines' id='aantmch' value='1'></input>
 </form>
</p>`
```

AFTER you update the DOM with the HTML, you can use

```
var mdwCount = document.getElementById("aantmdw").value;
var mchCount = document.getElementById("aantmch").value;
```

Comment: Yes, it is like the last one u mentioned. I use the htmlmessage variable in modal dialog, and i try to get both values from the inputs. I tried something like

Comment: var mdwCount = document.getElementById("aantmdw").value;
var mchCount = document.getElementById("aantmch").value; But it returns nulls

Comment: *"You cannot have newlines…"* – in Javascript **string literals**. I think that's an important qualifier. :) Also… ES6 template strings *can* have newlines.

Comment: @MarkieDoe the second chunk of code he has included doesn't match the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the point mentioned by **@mplungjan** of surrounding the html message content in quotes.

*Insert the **htmlmessage** in the **document** before fetching the dom element,*

as you have not inserted the **htmlmessage** , in the document, and before fetching any **document.getElementById("someId")** , will work only if a dom of "someId" is present in the document.